# AngularJs updating Bootstrap Progress bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'm trying to set the progress of the bar using angularJS

The variable is connected to an input using `ng-model`.

`javascript`

```
angular.module('progressTest', []);

angular.module('progressTest')
          .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.percent = 0;
})
```

`html`

```
<div ng-app="progressTest">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ mainCtrl.percent }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-model="mainCtrl.percent">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">%</span>
    </div>
    <span>{{ mainCtrl.percent }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The model is updating but there is no effect on the progress bar value.

> edit: forgot to add this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ishankhare07/pen/LNpRaY)

Comment: can you make fiddle or codepen?

Comment: I just added the code pen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Sorry, I thought it was to do with the controller. But the main problem was the `aria-valuenow` and `width` were not in sync with each other. Its **not sufficient** to bind `aria-valueNow`, but it is also **necessary to bind `width`** style. The below code works because we are binding the `width` using `ng-style`

```
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ mainCtrl.percent }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
  ng-style="{'width':mainCtrl.percent+'%'}">
```

Original answer to be used along with above update.

When you are using `controller as alias` syntax, you should use `this` instead of `$scope`. Try the below code. It will work.

```
angular.module('progressTest', []);

angular.module('progressTest')
          .controller('mainController', function () {
  this.percent = 0;
})
```